# How to customize FullCalendar for task scheduling and break down

Tags: reactjs, events, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want to customize task scheduling using ***FullCalendar*** ???,
And display the event start in half of day and end on half day  ???, Both have to be display like bellow,

I am using,

> React -  11.11.1  |
> @fullcalendar  - 6.1.10 (core, daygrid, interaction, react, resource, resource-timeline, timegrid)

[image]

If anyone know other library which support for this, please mention here.

This is my code sample,

```
    import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline'
import {useState} from "react";
function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
    return (
        <>
            <b>{eventInfo.timeText}</b>
            <i>{eventInfo?.event?.title}</i>
        </>
    )
}

const Text = (props) => {
    const events = [
        {
            id: 1,
            className: "HalfClass",
            resourceId: "a",
            title: "Taufik1",
            start: "2019-09-03 06:00",
            end: "2019-09-05 12:00",
            description: ""
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            resourceId: "b",
            title: "Smith",
            color: "#F6BB42",
            start: "2019-09-06",
            end: "2019-09-08"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            resourceId: "c",
            title: "Austin",
            start: "2019-09-04",
            end: "2019-09-08",
            description: ""
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            resourceId: "d",
            title: "Wong Ling",
            color: "#DA4453",
            start: "2019-09-04",
            end: "2019-09-06"
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            resourceId: "d",
            title: "Wong Ling",
            color: "#DA4453",
            start: "2019-09-10",
            end: "2019-09-12"
        }
    ]
    const asd = [
        {
            id: "a",
            title: "Auditorium A"
        },
        {
            id: "b",
            title: "Auditorium B"
        },
        {
            id: "c",
            title: "Auditorium C"
        },
        {
            id: "e",
            title: "Auditorium E"
        },
        {
            id: "d",
            title: "Auditorium D"
        }
    ]
    const [resources, setResources] = useState(asd);
    const [data, setDate] = useState(events);

    return (
        <div style={{width: '80%'}}>
            <p>Text file </p>
            {data && data?.length > 0 && (<FullCalendar
                id="calendar"
                nowIndicator
                plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                headerToolbar={{
                    left: "prev,next today",
                    center: "title",
                    right: "resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineDay"
                }}
                initialView="resourceTimelineWeek"
                editable
                initialDate="2019-09-03"
                slotDuration={{hours: 3}}
                slotLabelInterval={{hours: 24}}
                resources={resources}
                events={data}
                eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
            />)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Text;
```

This is my response,
[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelInterval can help you

Comment: Thank you @ADyson. I tried it, but it didn't work. Can you provide any examples?

Comment: It would be better if you show me exactly what you tried, in the form of a [mre] of the issue, and explain what effect it had when you used those settings. That way any examples or corrections I make will be more relevant to your exact situation. You can [edit] your question to include a code block. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, I added my code sample

Comment: Thanks. I could not reproduce your problem - the half-day event appears as it should with those settings - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYebQqB N.B. I don't use React, but it should not make much  difference - the fullCalendar API behaves the same underneath. The only thing I'm not sure about is that I don't know what your `renderEventContent` function does, as you didn't include it in your sample.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, Can you give me an example for renderEventContent function

Comment: Well that depends what you want it to do. Since your code specifies it I assumed you had already implemented something - hence why i asked you to show the function (in case what you have done relates to your problem somehow). But it's optional- you don't need it unless you want to change the default appearance of the events

Comment: Hi @ADyson. I added my full sample file. Still events not loading, but calendar loading correctly

Comment: Thanks. I added that to the demo at https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYebQqB but it still works fine. I can't understand why you would be unable to see any events. Perhaps it's some issue in React. Are there any errors in the browser's Console? Have you tried using it without the `eventContent` setting enabled?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. no errors in the browser. But still events not loading. I added my response screen.

Comment: Have you tried it without the eventContent function enabled?

Comment: yes, I tried, but didn't change it

Comment: In that case I'm sorry but I think I have reached the limit of my knowledge, and I can't help you any further. I assume the issue is with the way you've defined the events in react, but since I know almost nothing about react I can't be sure exactly what the mistake is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256236/discussion-between-nishan-madhuwantha-and-adyson).